# SQL Running sum by day/month

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has daily sales values.  I want to create a running total each month.  I attempted a window function but it continues to add rather than start over when a new month begins.

Query I was using.

```
select
date, name, sum(sales) over (partition by name order by date)
from sales.table

Date         Name     Sales
2016-01-01   John     140.75
2016-01-02   John     169.20
2016-01-03   John     600.25
....         ....      ....
2016-01-31   John     32731.91
2016-02-01   John     32914.81 <-- Start over for the month
```

Comment: Try adding month to the `partition by`.    Month and Year, actually, if you have more than one months' data in the table.

Comment: @TabAlleman that was so simple! Thank you!